# how i can solve this problem in flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

Launching lib\main.dart on SM A105F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\ABDERRAHIM\flutter-1\bouzid_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk:
Exception occurred while executing:
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:564)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2700)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1061)
at com
Error launching application on SM A105F.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB exited with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367108/adb-exited-with-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 1):

Your error states the following `java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)`. Do you have enough free space on your device?

Please search the web before posting a question: [Flutter - android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459928/flutter-android-os-parcelableexception-java-io-ioexception-requested-interna)

Answer (score 0):

**According to [@dariush f's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56417433/11404883) answer:**

1. ***Maybe your device/emulator's storage is full. Try deleting some apps or similar to free up storage.***

**Or**

2. ***Invalid package name . for example using capital letter in package name. use this to change package name in flutter***